# deleting a record using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, file, visual-c++

I am a complete beginner in c++, so bear with me. I have been asked to write a program and one of the functions is to delete a record from a file and place it in another file using arrays (with an unknown size hence the counter). I have tried many different methods but to no avail. Now I got the `abort()` error and I really don't know what to do or fix. Your help is greatly needed.

```
void DeletePatient ()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open ("patients.txt");

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open ("deletedpatients.txt");

    int i=0, flag=0, counter=0, deleteID, deletedindex;

    //Read contents into array

    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        infile>>IDnumber[i]>> FirstName [i] >> LastName [i] >> PhoneNumber [i] >> Nationality [i];
        i++;
        counter++;
    }

    if ( !infile )
        cout << "Error opening file\n";
    else  
    {
        cout<<"Enter ID number of patient to be deleted\n";
        cin >> deleteID;

        for(i=0;i<counter;i++)
        {
            if(deleteID==IDnumber[i])
            {

                infile >> IDnumber [i] >> FirstName [i] >> LastName [i] >> PhoneNumber [i] >> Nationality [i];

                outfile << IDnumber [i] <<" "<< FirstName [i]<<" " << LastName [i]<<" " << PhoneNumber [i]<<" " << Nationality [i];

                flag++;

                for(deletedindex=i; i<counter; deletedindex++)
                {
                    IDnumber[deletedindex]=IDnumber[deletedindex+1];
                    FirstName[deletedindex]=FirstName[deletedindex+1];
                    LastName[deletedindex]=LastName[deletedindex+1];
                    PhoneNumber[deletedindex]=PhoneNumber[deletedindex+1];
                    Nationality[deletedindex]=Nationality[deletedindex+1];
                }

            }
        }

        infile.close();

        if(flag==0)
            cout<<"User does not exsist\n";
        else
        {
            ofstream updatefile;
            updatefile.open("patients.txt");

            for ( i=0 ; i < counter; i++ ) //update file
            {

                updatefile << IDnumber [i] <<" "<< FirstName [i]<<" " << LastName [i]<<" " << PhoneNumber [i]<<" " << Nationality [i];
            }   
            cout << "Patient is deleted" << endl;
            updatefile.close();
        }
    }

    outfile.close ();
}
```

Comment: What is the size of the arrays? Because when reading you have no upper limit. Also, when deleting the last element in an array, `deletedindex+1` might not exist.

Comment: Where is the error happening ? How are you allocating the arrays ?

Comment: the original size is 200, but I use a counter to read the number of records there actually are so counter is the size, as for the error it happens right after I input the ID to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the condition of this loop:

```
for(deletedindex = i; i < counter; deletedindex++)
```

Neither `i` nor `counter` are modified inside the loop, so once you get in, you don't get out (without undefined behavior) - **infinite loop**.

Maybe, you meant something like:

```
for(deletedindex = i; deletedindex + 1 < counter; deletedindex++)
```

Anyways, your code needs serious refactoring - use **one** array of objects having these attributes, also consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, but can I ask why you used deletedindex+1 instead of just deletedindex? won't that cause a problem in the number of repetitions?

Comment: Because you're accessing elements like `IDnumber[deletedindex+1]`, you have to iterate one less time. It will access `IDnumber[count]` otherwise, which is one past the end of valid values, potentially out of array bounds.